# How do I fix command output in terminal is invisible on external monitor

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-terminal

Sometimes, when I run a command in Windows Terminal, the output of that command will be invisible until I select the text in the terminal, then it appears one whole line at a time, even if I don't select the line.

This is incredibly annoying and I'd like to know if there's a way to get this fixed.

There seems to be evidence that this only happens on external monitors on my laptops. My two monitors have different scaling factors (Laptop 200%, external 100%) which also seems to be related.

- Using Windows Terminal
- in Windows 10
- running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- inside WSL2

I have tried

- Restarting Windows Terminal
- Restarting my computer
- Changing the terminal color theme
- Sifting through the settings and changing other settings in the terminal
- Internet searching everything I can think of
- After [asking on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71651514/how-do-i-fix-command-output-in-terminal-is-invisible?noredirect=1#comment126635186_71651514) I have found this **only happens when I am using an external monitor**. (I'm using a laptop)
- After issuing a `reset` in the Ubuntu shell, `git status` is fine the first time, but after that text is still missing.
- Moving the Windows Terminal window to my primary display reveals all hidden text.

Example:

Run command, text is invisible (red boxes are censoring, not part of the problem)

[image]

Select some lines, and they become visible.

[image]

Select all the lines, and they are visible.

[image]

The text does not become visible on it's own.

Comment: Glad you reposted over here.  That "external monitor" info is probably a good lead.  I have a possible theory -- Could it be that it starts happening at some point after *swapping* from the laptop monitor to the external monitor?  In other words, if you *start* on the external monitor, does it still happen?  Another thought - Curious if a `reset` command in Ubuntu/WSL fixes the issue?

Comment: After `reset` the first `git status` is fine, the second is missing some lines, and the third is missing most lines. If text is invisible and I drag the window from external to laptop, the lines reappear. And finally, it does not appear to happen when the window is on my laptops internal display at all, so I think there is something about the external monitor that causes it. Two different laptops as well, same behavior.

Comment: Interesting - Perhaps a resizing issue when it moves to the external monitor as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6210)?

Comment: The two monitors do have different scaling rations, which could be related. I suppose a new monitor that can use the same scaling factor would be one solution. Not that I like running out to buy one, but this one is rather... old.

Comment: While I'm not going to try to talk you out of buying a new monitor ;-), could you temporarily set the display resolution on the external monitor so that it would match the scaling ratio?  That should tell us if this is really the problem, right?

Comment: It seems there is a workaround. When I change the ratio of the external monitor and switch it back, it seems to fix my invisible text issue until I move the window from monitor to monitor.

Comment: Sounds like kind of a painful workaround, but you might want to add that info to the Github issue.  Perhaps the Terminal team could tap into the same Windows "resize/repaint" hook that Windows uses when the resolution/ratio uses.  Mind if I write up an answer referencing the Github issue and your info on changing the monitor resolution/ratio?

Comment: Good point. I'll add my experience to the issue.

Comment: Curious - Does a simple resize of the Windows Terminal window (make it larger, at least) cause the missing text to re-appear?

Comment: Yes, resizing does also temporarily resolve the issue. I think my issue is different but related to the one you linked, so I [opened a new issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12793)

Comment: Perhaps different, but note the Microsoft Dev comment in the original issue -- *"So this will repro by just dragging the window across a DPI boundary as well"*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135176/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-nate).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "external monitor" hint, and some additional info in the comments, we determined that this appears likely to be due to a [known issue in Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6210).  When Windows Terminal is moved between two monitors with different scaling ratios, the Terminal window is incorrectly resized.  It appears that this resizing is what is causing lines to disappear (and then reappear when moved back to the original monitor).

Based on this info, you found that resizing Windows Terminal after dragging to the second monitor can cause the text to reappear.  Another possible (but perhaps less pleasant) workaround you found is that changing the resolution/scaling ratio on the external monitor will cause the text to reappear.