# Windows Terminal removing/skipping random lines of output

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

Windows Terminal (1.12.10982.0) keeps removing random lines from the output in Ubuntu/WSL - notice the gap in `irb`'s output between line 52 and 70:

```
irb(main):051:3*     file.each do |line|
irb(main):052:3*     key = API_KEY
        from (irb):62:in `block (4 levels) in enrich'
irb(main):070:2*   File.open("websites.txt", "r") do |file|
irb(main):071:3*     file.each do |line|
```

Here's a screenshot, to help clarify:

[image: Screenshot]

This happens randomly when using `irb` in Ubuntu.  It also occurs when pasting multiple lines into the shell in Ubuntu in Windows Terminal.

What can be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you give some more information?
What are you trying to achieve? What is it meant to look like? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I take it that this wasn't the same problem as [How do I fix command output in terminal is invisible on external monitor](https://superuser.com/q/1713554/1210833) that I linked to in your Stack Overflow question?

Comment: This might be one of those rare cases where a screenshot of the problem is better than text.  Also, have you tried the same thing in the legacy Windows console host (or another terminal app)?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds no, that's not the issue you linked to. Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/XlfKTNC.png. It happens randomly when pasting multiple lines of code into the terminal (Ubuntu). Doesn't happen in e.g. Powershell.

Comment: @alvaro88 Okay, so WSL/Ubuntu specific, then, *not* Windows Terminal, right?  Also, you say "pasted", but from the screenshot and question that looks like irb *output* rather than pasted text, is that right?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds it just cuts random lines, both pasted code and irb output.

Comment: @alvaro88 I've asked for this to be reopened.  I don't have any ideas right now.  Can you add the `wt --version` to the question?  Also, look over my edits and make sure they are accurate - Thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks for helping!